# Add reply to the comment in the pdfbox

Tags: java, annotations, pdfbox

I want to add the reply to the comment I entered for the annotation. But the code I have written produce no reply but only annotation and the comment. What am I missing? I am sharing my code. Also I want to add the creation date for the annotation, how should I do that?
Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Loading an existing document
    File file = new File("ABC.pdf");
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
    System.out.println("PDF loaded.");

    PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
    List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();

    PDColor color = new PDColor(new float[] {255f, 0, 0}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
    PDBorderStyleDictionary thickness = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
    thickness.setWidth((float)2);

    PDAnnotationSquareCircle rectangle = new PDAnnotationSquareCircle(PDAnnotationSquareCircle.SUB_TYPE_SQUARE);
    rectangle.setColor(color);
    rectangle.setBorderStyle(thickness);

    PDRectangle points = new PDRectangle();

    points.setLowerLeftX((float) 100);
    points.setLowerLeftY((float) 100);
    points.setUpperRightX((float) 300);
    points.setUpperRightY((float) 300);
    rectangle.setContents("Rectangle");
    rectangle.setRectangle(points);
    rectangle.getCOSObject().setString(COSName.T, "XYZ");

    PDAnnotationMarkup reply = new PDAnnotationMarkup();
    reply.getCOSObject().setName(COSName.SUBTYPE, PDAnnotationMarkup.RT_REPLY);
    reply.setContents("Hello 2");
    reply.setReplyType("R");
    reply.setInReplyTo(rectangle);

    annotations.add(rectangle);
    System.out.println("Rectangle is added.");

    // Save the file
    document.save(file);

    // Close the document
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: you don't actually store your reply

Comment: @Stultuske Do you mean, I have to add it to annotation, like the rectangle?

Comment: You need to call `annotations.add()` on that one IMHO. Additionally, RT_REPLY is not an annotation subtype. RT_REPLY is a reply type. Try creating an ordinary annotation first. If you're not sure, annotate a file with Adobe Reader and then look at it with PDFDebugger.

Comment: The other part of your question, use `setCreationDate()`. Works for markups.

Comment: Also check the PDF specification for the version. If it says "1.5" then set the version to 1.5 at least if it is less.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have referred the PDFDebugger and it helped a lot for replies to comment. But for the creation date, I am still unable to see the date in the comments after adding `rectangle.setCreationDate(creationDate)` where `creationDate` is `Calendar.getInstance()`. Do I need to add anything more?

Comment: try also `setModifiedDate(Calendar c)`.